# Creating JSON in Python and parsing in Java

Tags: java, android, python, json, gson

My application involves sending JSONs from a RESTful Python back-end server to an android device via HTTP requests. However, I keep getting a JsonParseException. Here is how the JSON is created and returned:

```
articleList = []
obj = Content.objects.filter(id = 332).values()[0]
articleList.append(obj)     
data = {'articleList' : articleList}        
return simplejson.dumps(data)
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
{\"articleList\": 
    [
        {\"ArticleName\": \"Test_ArticleName\\n\", \"ArticleText\":\"Test_ArticleText\"
         ,\"Author\": \"Test_Author\\n\", \"SourceID\": 18, \"Image\": \"NULL\", \"ImageLink\": \"NULL\", \"Video\": \"NULL\", \"PublicationDate\": \"8/15/2011 4:00AM\", \"VideoLink\": \"NULL\\n\", \"NumViews\": 0, \"Type\": \"NULL\", \"id\": 332}
    ]
}
```

When I copy and paste this string into Java, it works so I don't think the issue relates to the structure.

On the client I am using the GSON library to parse the JSON:

```
ArticleList articleList;
InputStream source = retrieveStream(urlStr);
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setVersion(1.0).create();
String json = convertStreamToString(source);
try {
    json = URLDecoder.decode(json,"UTF-8");
    articleList = gson.fromJson(json, ArticleList.class);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
    Log.e(TAG,"Decoding error: "+e1);
} catch (JsonParseException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Parsing error: "+e);
}

private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        Log.i(TAG, sb.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

My ArticleList.class just contains

```
List<Article> articleList
```

and my Article.class contains all the keys "ArticleName", "ArticleText", etc..

The exception that I am getting is:

```
Parsing error: com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Expecting object found: "{\"articleList\": [{\"ArticleName\": \"Test_ArticleName\\n\", \"ArticleText\": \"Test_ArticleText\", \"Author\": \"Test_Author\\n\", \"SourceID\": 18, \"Image\": \"NULL\", \"ImageLink\": \"NULL\", \"Video\": \"NULL\", \"PublicationDate\": \"8/15/2011 4:00AM\", \"VideoLink\": \"NULL\\n\", \"NumViews\": 0, \"Type\": \"NULL\", \"id\": 332}
```

I think I might be getting this exception because of unescaped quotes but I'm not sure how to deal with that. I even tried decoding the JSON before converting to an ArticleList object.

Comment: Erm, well ... yes, that's not valid JSON. See all those backslashes? Not only that but you seem to be concatenating sevel lines together with newlines and then expecting it to be valid JSON, which it then wouldn't be.

Comment: The double quotes were escaped in Python but I'm not sure how to un-escape them since URL.decoder didn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Do you think the "NULL" values are actually processed as Null in Java?

Comment: Ah .. I didn't think of that. Now I have a new issue ..

Comment: @slouie - then you need to fix your python. The output isn't valid JSON; it has nothing to do with Java or UrlEncoder. json.dumps() should not produce anything like that.

Comment: Already fixed by changing return to return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), mimetype="application/json"). Also the NULL happens to work. I tried it.

Answer (score 2):

Pasting the JSON String you've provided into a String of a Java program, works - due to the fact that quotation marks (acting as String notation termination characters) are escaped. These quotation marks should hoever **not** be escaped, when reading the JSON from an external resource (a Stream, document or similar), and the JSON should therefore read:

```
{"articleList": 
    [
        {"ArticleName": "Test_ArticleName\n", "ArticleText":"Test_ArticleText"
         ,"Author": "Test_Author\n", "SourceID": 18, "Image": "NULL", "ImageLink": "NULL", "Video": "NULL", "PublicationDate": "8/15/2011 4:00AM", "VideoLink": "NULL\n", "NumViews": 0, "Type": "NULL", "id": 332}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I fixed the issue by changing the return in the python code to return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), mimetype="application/json")